# Browsers support for sub pixel font sizes (eg. 15.5px) in CSS

Tags: css, fonts

Im changing a site from using font-a to font-b.

The fonts are very similar but not exactly the same.

font-b is slightly smaller than font-a so where font-a used `font-size : 15px;` i want to use for font-b `font-size : 15.5px`.

But am unsure of the Browser support for sub pixel font sizes and even if they work at all, eg. would a browser just round to the nearest whole pixel eg. 15.5px would become 16px.

Does anyone have any info on this ?

Answer (score 2):

use `0.969em` this is equivalent to `15.5px`, [converted here](https://nekocalc.com/px-to-em-converter)

[sub pixel guide](https://chenhuijing.com/blog/about-subpixel-rendering-in-browsers/)